# The 'liberal arts' tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The small ['liberal arts' tag](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liberal-arts) is defined in the tag wiki as:

> Questions having to do with liberal arts subjects such as literature, languages, art, music, philosophy, and history.

However, several of the questions seem to be about liberal arts colleges:

- [Research statement for liberal arts college: how much detail should I go into?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/57560/research-statement-for-liberal-arts-college-how-much-detail-should-i-go-into)
- [Learning Style Issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/98816/learning-style-issues)
- [What are typical examples of "scholarly work"?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/138194/what-are-typical-examples-of-scholarly-work)
- [Where to find details on Bachelor degrees majoring in IT?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/119554/where-to-find-details-on-bachelor-degrees-majoring-in-it)

Whereas others are about liberal arts:

- [How to judge the quality of education of an art school?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/107034/how-to-judge-the-quality-of-education-of-an-art-school)
- [Is taking ideas from an art critic plagiarism?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/82185/is-taking-ideas-from-an-art-critic-plagiarism)
- [Colloquial forms (let's...) in articles](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/127932/colloquial-forms-lets-in-articles)

Should this be separated into two tags or otherwise cleaned up?

Comment: Is there even any group of disciplines that call themselves *liberal arts* and have inherent commonalities in their academic culture? Wikipedia directly redirects *liberal arts* to *liberal-arts education.*

Comment: I do not know. Maybe the tag could be renamed into liberal-arts-colleges , if that is a coherent concept, and removed from the then irrelevant questions.

Comment: liberal-arts-colleges might be a coherent concept in one specific country, but outside there Wikipedia suggests that it's an extremely recent import. Perhaps us-style-liberal-arts-colleges would be a more accurate name.

Comment: @PeterTaylor There are also tags nih and nsf, as well as irb, and probably other regional tags without explicit mention of a country or such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Eliminate the tag as too vague
- Create a new tag for "Liberal Arts Colleges"

The current tag description is wrong.  "Liberal arts" does not mean arts and humanities.  The traditional meaning is grammar, logic, rhetoric, arithmetic, geometry, astronomy, and music.  Other sciences are not in the traditional list because they did not exist at the time the list was made.

Comment: I agree. In particular, the three questions over there that are not about liberal arts colleges all could have a more specific tag, and both those tags already exist.

Comment: I edited the tag away from the three linked questions about specific liberal arts. Maybe more activity later.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to say let's leave them be.  Yes, there are two distinct meaning here, but :

1. the meanings are closely related (at least in the US system), and
2. the number of questions is small enough  that it's probably not causing any real difficulties to have them lumped together.

Comment: Yeah, the US caveat is needed - I had little idea what "liberal arts" meant until I moved here ;-)

Comment: Since there are only a few questions, it is easy and painless to fix the matter.